# create a multidimensional array for pdo select

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

```
    while ($v = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $basicinfo[] = array('sysid' => $v['sysid'], 'thesis' => $v['thesis']);
    }
    $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $basicinfo)));
    echo json_encode(array_values($input), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

this is how i make an array from database i want to make a multidimensional array that i can access from ajax request like `data[i].group[j].leader` i want to create another array inside the first array which is named thesis. I want to name that array `group` to represent the number of group that are taking up the subject thesis. Inside this array i want to put the value of the members of that group. I can also add another array inside the array thesis, it will be an array with same level as the array `group`. i have tried doing it like this

```
$basicinfo[$group] = array('sysid' => $v['sysid'], 'thesis' => $v['thesis'],"$group=>array('leader' => $v('leader_name'))");
```

I want the array to look like this

```
[{
    "sysid": "015-08-0004-001-063-2001",
    "subject": "thesis",
    "group": {
        "groupid": "1",
        "groupleader": "John",
    },
    "adviser": {
        "advisername": "Prof Smith",
    }
}]
```

i want it like this so i can access each array in the ajax(jquery) like

`data[i].group[j].leader`
`data[i].adviser[j].advisername`

`Update`

[image: adviser tbl]
[image: group tbl]
[image: student tbl]
[image: subject tbl]

i still need to add more table and i think more columns for now this is what i am working with